# A treatment of mathematical foundations with motivation from physics

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, reference-request, mathematical-physics

I am looking for a work that treats the foundations of mathematics (linear algebra, real analysis, vector analysis, complex analysis…) in particular insofar they find application in mathematical physics and are presented with direct motivation from the field of [mathematical] physics.

The best thing I found in this regards so far is

- Mathematical Physics by Sadri Hassani
- Physics for Mathematicians, Mechanics I by Michael Spivak

I do have various gripes with both of these books though, the former is more of a collection of knowledge rather than a pedagogical presentation of it, the latter is focused on physics rather than mathematics and rather convoluted for my taste.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to specify what kind of physics you are trying to get into. There's also [Susan Fowler's list](https://www.susanjfowler.com/blog/2016/8/13/so-you-want-to-learn-physics).

Comment: I don't actually want to learn physics, I want to learn mathematics in regards to physics. The reason for this being that I am a philosophy student who is focusing partially on the intersection between the two as part of his studies and need to get some formal knowledge under my belt.

Comment: I think you have to separate Vector Analysis as a special and very interesting case, since its establishment on the physics curriculum really did involve Oliver Heaviside's all out war (in the written word) with several academics from the Hamilton school who much preferred Quaternion Analysis.  To his credit E.T Whittaker stayed neutral leaving Vector/Quaternion Analysis out of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis